# alert the value of an HTML tag generated from javascript using - jquery "attr"

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a function which is generating a `<tr>`, and for each  of this `table`, there is an `Update` Button along with the database values retrieved as JSON. This `tr` is appended to a table using  `$("#RawMatTable").html(RawMat);`
This automatically generated `table` is first viewed for new entries with the help of `input` tags in each `td` and can later be updated with the help of `Update` button - the code is as follows -

```
function GetRawMaterial() {

     var id = $('#UsrSelectedBprNo').val();
          $.ajax({
              type: "POST",
              url: "http://XXXXXXXXXX:XXXX/XXXXX.svc/XXXXX/" + id,
              data: "{}",
              contentType: "application/json",
              dataType:"json", 
              success:  function (msg) {                    
                   var RawMat = '';                               
                   $.each(msg, function(i,v){
                   RawMat += "<tr><td>" + "" + "</td><td>" + v.RM_Name + "</td><td id='sapCode"+i+"'>" + v.RM_SAP_Code + "</td><td>" + v.Unit+ "</td><td>" + v.Std_Qty + "</td><td>" + v.Allowable_Range + "</td><td>" + "<input type='text' id='actqty"+i+"'/>" + "</td><td>" + "<input type='text' id=''/>" + "</td><td>" + "<input type='text' id=''/>" + "</td><td>" + "<input type='text' id=''/>" + "</td><td>" + "<button id="+i+">Update</button>" + "</td></tr>";                       

                   $("#RawMatTable").html(RawMat);

                   $('button').click(function() {                               
                   var attrValue = $(this).attr('id'); 

                   alert (attrValue);
                   });                                         
                   });
```

Once this is done.. i.e. the rows are generated, the values from within these tags should be used for my next function as inputs. These values are acting as my keys for my SQL query.
For e.g. the value of "v.RM_SAP_Code" acts as a reference and following is my next function

```
  function UpdateRawMaterial() {
             $.ajax({
                 type: "PUT",
                 url: "http://XXXX.XXX.XXX/DRLServiceHost/BPRService.svc/UpdateRawMat/ " + BPRNo + "/" + SAP_Code + "/" + Act_Qty + "/" + In_House_Batch + "/" + Equip_Id + "/" + RM_Remark,
                 data: "{}",
                 contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                 dataType: "json",
                 success: function (result, txtstatus) {
                     alert(txtstatus);
                    },
                 error: function (result) {
                     alert("jQuery Error:" + result.statusText);
                 }
             });
         };
```

My question here is how do I read the value of my dynamically generated HTML tags, on a button Click - which is in the same row?
More clearly, A row's "Update" button click should give the value of an HTML tag within the same row.

I am only able to get the id value of the clicked button so far, and unable to get an idea of how to read the other values.

Kindly let me know if this needs to be elaborated more....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to work from something like this:

```
// Listen to click events on the button
$("button").click(function(e) {
    // Find the input field by first finding the parenting tr, then find the input
    var input = $(this).parents("tr").find("input[type='text']");
    alert(input.val());
});
```

In the callback function, `this` refers to the button, and you can find the parent `tr` by using `.parents('tr')`. After you have found the parent tr, you can find the input field.

(This requires a certain structure of the HTML, so if you do major refactoring, the code might not work)

Take a look at [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fKhhg/) to see it in action.

Comment: fantastic.. I was worried if my question was too long/un-descriptive... only thing I did is, I used input.html() instead of input.val() as I needed values from a <td> :)

Answer (score 0):

Once inside the button click handler use the jQuery [DOM Traversal](http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/) methods to access the other elements in that row. For efficiency you should just set the html once at the end and you can use [on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) to register just one handler rather than one for each button.

```
var RawMat = '';

$.each(msg, function(i,v)
{
    RawMat += "<tr><td>" + "" + "</td><td>" + v.RM_Name + "</td><td id='sapCode"+i+"'>" + v.RM_SAP_Code + "</td><td>" + v.Unit+ "</td><td>" + v.Std_Qty + "</td><td>" + v.Allowable_Range + "</td><td>" + "<input type='text' id='actqty"+i+"'/>" + "</td><td>" + "<input type='text' id=''/>" + "</td><td>" + "<input type='text' id=''/>" + "</td><td>" + "<input type='text' id=''/>" + "</td><td>" + "<button id="+i+">Update</button>" + "</td></tr>";
});

var $html = $(RawMat);

$html.on('click', 'button', function()
{
    // cache jquery object
    var $this = $(this);

    // alert id
    alert($this.attr('id'));

    // get the tr parent
    var $tr = $this.closest('tr');

    // alert 'RM_Name'
    $tr.find('td:nth-child(2)').text();
});

$("#RawMatTable").html($html);
```